# Creating a second class object through a method of a first class object - Python

Tags: python, class, object

I'm trying to generate a second object through the method of the first object. The objective here is to send a an dictionary item to the ledger list of the second object.

The line that should achieve this is:

food.transfer(20, "Utils")

where food its the first object of Category class.
The problem is that this section "{"amount": amount, "Transfer from: ": self.name}", from the last line, should be appended to the ledger of the second object not the first, like it results from the code below.

Please don't judge, i'm a beginner - (Python)

```
def transfer(self, amount, other_category):

    total = 0

    for dicts in self.ledger:
        for key in dicts:
            if key == "amount":
                total += dicts[key]
    if amount <= total:
        new_obj = Category(f"{other_category}")
        self.ledger.append({"amount": -1 * amount, "Transfer to: ": f"{other_category}"})
        new_obj.ledger.append({"amount": amount, "Transfer from: ": self.name})
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: That should do what you want. If it's appending to the same ledger, I suspect you have a problem with the way you define the ledger attribute in the class.

Comment: the ledger list it's defined from the start of the class definition :

Comment: It needs to be in the `__init__()` method, `self.ledger = []`. If it's defined in the class, then all instances share the same ledger.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: Good advise, thanks, that solves the problem partially, but i still have an issue while trying to define the second object in the transfer method of the first one, in order to append that dict. to the second object's ledger.

Comment: food.transfer(20, "Utils") -- Here it shoud add to the first object's ledger an dict, and also it shoud create and add the second object and apend to it's ledger another dict displayed in the code above.
print(Utils.ledger) -- here python does not recognize the second object : "NameError: name 'Utils' is not defined"

Comment: If anyone is in need to help me :), i want within the transfer method, to acces the reference of a specific object created: If my reference is x = Category("Object") i want to acces that x and append a new dict to it's existing ledger.